# finding records relative to today

Tags: sql

I have a table named `dbstorage` which has columns like `year` and `weekno`.

I need to select the year and weekno which is less than current year and current week.

I used:

```
select * from dbstorage where year<=2011 and weekno<=13.
```

But it is not giving the correct data like if I have a value
year:2010 and weekno:25 means, the query is not selecting this record.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can split it out into two cases and use `or`

```
SELECT * /*<-- But don't use * List the columns explicitly*/
FROM   dbstorage
WHERE  ( year = 2011
         AND weekno <= 13 )
        OR year < 2011
```

**Edit**

But `And` logic may well be more efficient

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbstorage
WHERE  ( year <= 2011 )
       AND ( year < 2011
              OR weekno <= 13 )
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to split up the search into multiple parts:

```
select * from dbstorage 
where
    (year = 2011 and weekno <= 13) -- will catch all weeks in 2011 PRIOR to this one
    or (year < 2011) -- will catch all weeks in 2010 and earlier
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server you can also do:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbstorage
WHERE (year = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE())
      AND weekno <= DATEPART(ww, GETDATE()))
OR year < DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE())
```